# (initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, live-usb

So I wanted to install Ubuntu on my PC using a USB-Stick. I thought it would be easy because I have already done it multiple times in the past (not on this specific pc, but on my laptop). I followed the official Ubuntu Tutorial, so I downloaded the .iso File, with the right bit-system (64 bit) and used Rufus to make my USB-Stick bootable.

I booted from it, choose "install ubuntu" (I also tried "try ubuntu without installing", but everything happened exactly the same). So some lines of code showed up with the time on the left, then a ubuntu splash screen appeared, where just a loading symbol was. Then, more lines of appeared, and finally the error: (initramfs): Unable to find a medium containing a live file system.

I tried many, many different things: I tried installing it onto my laptop with the same .iso file & the same usb-stick, and everything worked fine. But when I tried to use it on my PC, it didn't work. I tried different USB-Sticks, where it worked on my laptop but didnt't on my PC, I tried different hard drives, different flashing programs (Rufus, UUI) and different .iso Files: same problem...

I obviously searched the internet for solutions, but I couldn't find anything that would help me. Btw, I set my SATA Mode to AHCI, as often suggested.

I think it doesn't rely on neither the USB-Stick, the Hard Drive nor the Program used to create the bootable USB-Stick.

Comment: What make/model PC? Can you boot to recovery mode? Please clarify... booting to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in "try Ubuntu" mode did, or did not, work properly? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I can't tell you my specific PC parts rn, I'm not at home now. But as I wrote in the question, "try Ubuntu" didn't work. Everything happened exactly like it did when I chose "Install Ubuntu". The same Error occured.

Comment: The "some lines of code showed up with the time on the left" sounds like a kernel crash. Ubuntu may not be compatible with your computer. Once you get the make/model of your computer, search here, and on Google, to check Ubuntu compatibility.

Comment: @heynnema I sesrched on google but didn't find an official hardware compatible sheet or sth like that. Do you something like a direct link? Thanks for your help tho!

Comment: Tell me the make/model of your computer. Can you take a picture of "some lines of code showed up with the time on the left"?

Answer (score 1):

My PC has built in graphics, but I had been using an external graphics card.

The installation was successful when I used the onboard GPU (without the external graphics card plugged in).